# Wordpress save_post hook has the wrong post?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I'm getting some odd results saving meta values to my custom post types using the save_post hook. The data is saved to the incorrect post.

If I log the post ID using the code below, i see that the is is not the correct, that is while i edit post 7890, the log entry is 3345 (and thats where the saved data is put)

Have i misunderstood how the save_post hook works? Any help appreciated :)

```
add_action('save_post','save_data');
function save_data($post_id){
        $file = 'log.txt';
        $copystring = $post_id ."\n";
        file_put_contents($file, $copystring, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are using it correctly. The $post_id should be the ID of the post to save. Read more here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

However there could be various reasons why you are receiving the wrong post ID here.

- Saving the post triggers the save process of another post
- you are receiving some revision ID
- you are sending wrong ID data from your form
- maybe others ...

In the save post hook callback you should check if the post is of the correct post type and that it is not a revision or something.

```
$post = get_post($post_id);

if($post->post_type != 'desired-post-type') {
return;
}

if(wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) {
return;
}
```

... maybe some other checks.

What is post 3345? Print it to your console and check. Most probably it is of a different post type or you are submitting the wrong ID.

Comment: Thanks so much Blackbam,

Post-types varied, its wasnt a revision, and my form is the default WP one. But your suggestion of 'Saving the post triggers the save process of another post' was spot on! 

There was some code in another function, calling 'wp_update_post' and it wasnt working properly - thanks for sending me down the right road :)

v

Answer (score 1):

The `save_post` hook takes 3 arguments `($post_id, $post, $update)` and it also can be attached to a post type: `save_post_{$post->post_type}`.
If `$update === false` a brand new post is being created.

There are checks that must be put in place as well before doing our custom actions. The error you're facing much probably is a post revision being saved.

Let's say the CPT is "jobs".

```
add_action( 'save_post_jobs', 'save_data_so', 10, 3 );

function save_data_so( $id, $post, $update ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;

    # A wp_nonce_field is present, check for it
    // if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
    //    return;

    # Not sure if necessary when using save_post_POST-TYPE
    if ( 'revision' == $post->post_type )
        return;

    # Do your thing
}
```